# Which of the following approaches is more suitable for CUDA parallelism?

Tags: c++, vector, cuda, reduce, dot-product

I found that there are two approaches to calculating dot products of two vectors in CUDA:

Which of the following approaches is more suitable for CUDA parallelism?

1. The approach used in the given code is a simple parallelization
   approach using a single block of threads.

   The `dotProductKernel()` function computes the dot product of two
   input vectors `a` and `b` using parallel processing on the GPU. Each
   thread in the single block processes a segment of the input vectors
   and calculates a partial sum. The partial sums are then summed up
   using `atomicAdd()` to produce the final dot product.

   ````
   #include <vector>
   #include <iostream>

   __global__ void dotProductKernel(int *a, int *b, int *result, int n) {
       //Get the thread index
       int tid = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
       //Only calculate if thread index is valid
       if (tid < n) {
          int sum = 0;
          //Perform dot product calculation for this thread's segment of the arrays
          for (int i = tid; i < n; i+= blockDim.x * gridDim.x) {
              sum += a[i] * b[i];
          }
          //Atomically add this thread's result to the shared result
          atomicAdd(result, sum);
       } }

   int main() {
       int n = 10000;

       // Use vectors instead of raw pointers
       std::vector<int> a(n), b(n);
       int *c = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));

       // Initialize the input vectors
       for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
           a[i] = i+1;
           b[i] = i+1;
       }
       *c = 0;


           // Allocate memory on the GPU
       int* d_a, *d_b, *d_c;
       cudaMalloc(&d_a, a.size() * sizeof(int));
       cudaMalloc(&d_b, b.size() * sizeof(int));
       cudaMalloc(&d_c, 1 * sizeof(int));

       // Copy vectors to GPU
       cudaMemcpy(d_a, a.data(), a.size() * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
       cudaMemcpy(d_b, b.data(), b.size() * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
       cudaMemcpy(d_c, c, 1 * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

       // Launch kernel
       dotProductKernel<<<1, 1024>>>(d_a, d_b, d_c, n);

       // Copy result back from GPU
       cudaMemcpy(c, d_c, 1 * sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

       // Free GPU memory
       cudaFree(d_a);
       cudaFree(d_b);
       cudaFree(d_c);

       // Print first 10 elements
       for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
           std::cout << *c << '\n';
       }

       free(c); } ```
   ````
2. This code uses a parallel reduction approach.

   In the `dotProductKernel()` function, each thread computes a partial
   sum of the dot product of two input vectors `a` and `b`, and stores
   the result in a shared memory array results. The partial sums are
   calculated in parallel using multiple threads, with each thread
   processing a segment of the input vectors.

   In the `sumResultsKernel()` function, a single thread sums up the
   partial results stored in the shared memory array results and stores
   the final result in a separate memory location pointed to by the
   result. This final reduction operation is also performed in parallel
   using multiple threads.

   ````
   #include <vector>
   #include <iostream>

   __global__ void dotProductKernel(int *a, int *b, int *results, int n) {
       //Get the thread index
       int tid = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
       //Only calculate if thread index is valid
       if (tid < n) {
          int sum = 0;
          //Perform dot product calculation for this thread's segment of the arrays
          for (int i = tid; i < n; i+= blockDim.x * gridDim.x) {
              sum += a[i] * b[i];
          }
          //Store this thread's result in the shared results array
          results[blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x] = sum;
       } }

   __global__ void sumResultsKernel(int *results, int *result, int n) {
       //Get the thread index
       int tid = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
       //Only calculate if thread index is valid
       if (tid == 0) {
          int sum = 0;
          //Sum up the partial results
          for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
              sum += results[i];
          }
          //Store the final result
          *result = sum;
       } }

   int main() {
       int n = 10000;

       // Use vectors instead of raw pointers
       std::vector<int> a(n), b(n);
       int *c = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));

       // Initialize the input vectors
       for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
           a[i] = i+1;
           b[i] = i+1;
       }
       *c = 0;

       // Determine the grid size and block size
       int blockSize = 1024;
       int gridSize = (n + blockSize - 1) / blockSize;

       // Allocate memory on the GPU
       int* d_a, *d_b, *d_results, *d_result;
       cudaMalloc(&d_a, a.size() * sizeof(int));
       cudaMalloc(&d_b, b.size() * sizeof(int));
       cudaMalloc(&d_results, gridSize * blockSize * sizeof(int));
       cudaMalloc(&d_result, 1 * sizeof(int));

       // Copy vectors to GPU
       cudaMemcpy(d_a, a.data(), a.size() * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
       cudaMemcpy(d_b, b.data(), b.size() * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
       cudaMemset(d_results, 0, gridSize * blockSize * sizeof(int));
       cudaMemset(d_result, 0, sizeof(int));

       // Launch kernel
       dotProductKernel<<<gridSize, blockSize>>>(d_a, d_b, d_results, n);

       // Sum up the partial results
       sumResultsKernel<<<1, 1024>>>(d_results, d_result, gridSize * blockSize);

       // Copy result back from GPU
       cudaMemcpy(c, d_result, 1 * sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

       // Free GPU memory
       cudaFree(d_a);
       cudaFree(d_b);
       cudaFree(d_results);
       cudaFree(d_result);

       // Print the result
       std::cout << "Dot product = " << *c << '\n';

       free(c); } ```
   ````

Comment: @njuffa, *Did you mean to compare an implementation using atomic adds with one using parallel reduction?* --- actually yes.

Comment: It would be better to explain the two algorithms in words (with the code demonstrating the text), rather than asking people to interpret code.

Comment: both are correct conceptually.  A dot product is a kind of a reduction.  If you study [canonical reduction material](https://developer.download.nvidia.com/assets/cuda/files/reduction.pdf) you will realize that there is more than one way to achieve a reduction (also [here](https://www.olcf.ornl.gov/calendar/cuda-atomics-reductions-and-warp-shuffle/)).  The first method attempts to compute the dot-product in a single kernel call. The second uses a hierarchical method, with the 2nd kernel call summing the results of the first.  In many cases, the first method can be faster due to this difference.

Comment: The first code happens to be written using only a single block, but there is no structural reason to do so, and for a wide range of problems it will generally perform faster if the number of blocks launched is equal to the number of SMs in the GPU, or a whole-number multiple of it. To make it approximately optimal, you would want to have a intra-threadblock reduction step added to it, and reduce the final atomic to be performed by only one thread in each block.  Such a methodology is covered in the material I previously linked (2nd link).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only reason I know of that people use CUDA is to make their code run faster.  I'm not sure what "suitable for CUDA parallelism" means, or why it would be necessary to consider something other than performance as a figure of merit.

If we consider performance, then, the best approach will be a combination of the two methods you have shown.  In CUDA, the first two priorities of any CUDA programmer are:

1. expose enough parallelism; this roughly translates into "use lots of threads in your kernel launch"
2. make efficient use of memory

The first method makes efficient use of memory in that it does a running sum reduction out of global memory into each thread using a coalesced grid-stride loop.  It makes inefficient use of memory by unnecessarily loading the atomic mechanism with potentially lots of atomics.  Even in the suboptimal case shown, there are 1024 atomic calls when only one or zero are needed.

The first method is also not optimal in that it launches only 1 block.  This is almost never optimal in CUDA (not enough threads); it leaves much of the GPU idle.

To rectify these problems and come close to optimal speed, we will want to combine aspects of both methods:

- use a running sum per thread to initially gather all values from global memory in a coalesced fashion
- choose a grid size to "fill" the GPU being used
- once the running product-sums per thread are complete, perform an intra-threadblock reduction.  A canonical shared memory sweep style reduction is probably optimal here.
- the preceding step will place the threadblock partial sum into a single location.  Atomically add this location to the global sum.  This eliminates the need for multiple kernel launches (each of which will cost a minimum of 5 microseconds or more) as might be used in the second method, and other canonical reduction material.

The following achieves these design goals:

```
const int BLOCK_SIZE=512; // must be a power of 2 less than 2048, and preferably larger than 32
template <typename T>
__global__ void dotProductKernel(const T * __restrict__ a, const T * __restrict__ b, T * __restrict__ result, size_t n)
{
    __shared__ T smem[BLOCK_SIZE];
    //Get the thread index
    size_t tid = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    T sum = 0;
    //Perform dot product calculation for this thread's segment of the arrays
    for (size_t i = tid; i < n; i+= gridDim.x*blockDim.x) {
      sum += a[i] * b[i];
      }
    //Perform threadblock sweep reduction
    smem[threadIdx.x] = sum;
    for (int i = BLOCK_SIZE>>1; i > 0; i>>=1){
      __syncthreads();
      if (threadIdx.x < i) smem[threadIdx.x] += smem[threadIdx.x+i];}      
    //Atomically add this block's result to the global result
    if ((!threadIdx.x) && (tid < n)) atomicAdd(result, smem[0]);
}
```

Again, you would typically want to launch the above kernel with a number of threads per block defined by `BLOCK_SIZE` and a number of blocks as a whole number positive multiple of the number of SMs in your GPU.  Some tuning of these numbers may be necessary.  For a starting point, I would choose a `BLOCK_SIZE` of 512 and either two times the number of SMs, three times the number of SMs, or four times the number of SMs, as the number of blocks to launch.

This method will generally work well for larger dot-products.  Special adaptations might be desirable for very small dot products, where the length of the vector is less than the instantaneous thread-carrying capacity of the GPU (number of SMs times maximum number of threads per SM).  For example, you might choose `BLOCK_SIZE` of 32 for very small dot products.

Some of these concepts will be covered in units 3-4 of [this online training](https://www.olcf.ornl.gov/cuda-training-series/) (basic cuda optimization goals) and some additional topics (reductions and atomics) are covered in unit 5 of that training.

As a final note, this question seems oriented towards "learning".  If the goal is to implement something for production, the usual advice is to use a library implementation when/where available, and [CUBLAS](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html) includes a [dot-product](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html#cublas-t-dot), albeit not for integer types.  You can also realize a dot-product with for example [thrust](https://github.com/NVIDIA/thrust) [transform_reduce](https://thrust.github.io/doc/group__transformed__reductions_ga0d4232a9685675f488c3cc847111e48d.html).

Responding to a question in the comments below, here is a test case comparing my method vs. the first method presented in the question:

```
$ cat t11.cu
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#define USECPSEC 1000000ULL

unsigned long long dtime_usec(unsigned long long start=0){

  timeval tv;
  gettimeofday(&tv, 0);
  return ((tv.tv_sec*USECPSEC)+tv.tv_usec)-start;
}

#ifdef USE_BAD
__global__ void dotProductKernel(int *a, int *b, int *result, int n)
{
    //Get the thread index
    int tid = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    //Only calculate if thread index is valid
    if (tid < n) {
       int sum = 0;
       //Perform dot product calculation for this thread's segment of the arrays
       for (int i = tid; i < n; i+= blockDim.x * gridDim.x) {
           sum += a[i] * b[i];
       }
       //Atomically add this thread's result to the shared result
       atomicAdd(result, sum);
    }
}
#else
const int BLOCK_SIZE=512; // must be a power of 2 less than 2048, and preferably larger than 32
template <typename T>
__global__ void dotProductKernel(const T * __restrict__ a, const T * __restrict__ b, T * __restrict__ result, size_t n)
{
    __shared__ T smem[BLOCK_SIZE];
    //Get the thread index
    size_t tid = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    T sum = 0;
    //Perform dot product calculation for this thread's segment of the arrays
    for (size_t i = tid; i < n; i+= gridDim.x*blockDim.x) {
      sum += a[i] * b[i];
      }
    //Perform threadblock sweep reduction
    smem[threadIdx.x] = sum;
    for (int i = BLOCK_SIZE>>1; i > 0; i>>=1){
      __syncthreads();
      if (threadIdx.x < i) smem[threadIdx.x] += smem[threadIdx.x+i];}
    //Atomically add this block's result to the global result
    if ((!threadIdx.x) && (tid < n)) atomicAdd(result, smem[0]);
}
#endif

int main(){

  const int sz = 1048576;
  int *a, *b, *c;
  cudaMallocManaged(&a, sz*sizeof(a[0]));
  cudaMallocManaged(&b, sz*sizeof(b[0]));
  cudaMallocManaged(&c, sizeof(c[0]));
  for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++) {a[i] = 1; b[i] = 2;}
  c[0] = 0;
  cudaMemPrefetchAsync(a, sz*sizeof(a[0]), 0);
  cudaMemPrefetchAsync(b, sz*sizeof(b[0]), 0);
  cudaMemPrefetchAsync(c, sizeof(c[0]), 0);
  // warm-up
#ifdef USE_BAD
  dotProductKernel<<<1, 1024>>>(a, b, c, sz);
#else
  dotProductKernel<<<128, BLOCK_SIZE>>>(a, b, c, sz);
#endif
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  c[0] = 0;
  cudaMemPrefetchAsync(c, sizeof(c[0]), 0);
  unsigned long long dt = dtime_usec(0);
#ifdef USE_BAD
  dotProductKernel<<<1, 1024>>>(a, b, c, sz);
#else
  dotProductKernel<<<128, BLOCK_SIZE>>>(a, b, c, sz);
#endif
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  dt = dtime_usec(dt);
  cudaError_t err = cudaGetLastError();
  if (err != cudaSuccess)
    std::cout << cudaGetErrorString(err) << std::endl;
  else {
    std::cout << c[0] << std::endl;
    std::cout << "time: " << dt  << "us" << std::endl;}
}

$ nvcc -o t11 t11.cu -DUSE_BAD
$ ./t11
2097152
time: 185us
$ nvcc -o t11 t11.cu
$ ./t11
2097152
time: 15us
$
```

I also note after some further testing that if the example 1 in the question is modified to have an appropriate number of blocks in the kernel launch, it will be approximately the same speed (within about 1%) of the kernel I have outlined in my answer.  So the atomic pressure does not appear to be a serious concern for my testing so far.

Comment: I have just tested the timing of the two, and the first one seems to be running 2x faster. Is this expected?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  Did you read my comments under the question?  The first method can be faster of the two you have shown.  My method will be generally faster than the first method you have shown.

Comment: I've edited my answer to show an example performance comparison.

Comment: I wanted to mention my source code in my OP.

Comment: So you are comparing the first example in your question to the second example in your question?

Comment: Yes............

Comment: I already said in my comments under your question that the first one of your examples could be faster.  Here is what I said: " In many cases, the first method can be faster due to this difference. "  Performance evaluation will also depend on the test case size and the GPU you are running on.  Your test case size of 10000 elements is on the small side.